# Basic PHP Upload script with no result

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a very simple upload script.  Here is my HTML file that allows a user to submit a file:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

And then here is my PHP file that actually places the file on my server

```
 <?php 
 echo "starting the upload initially";
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
 ?>
```

I have the html saved at url.com/uploading.html and the php saved at url.com/uploader.php

After loading the HTML page and putting a file in the uploader the browser redirects me to the php file but then doesn't do anything further, not even print out that initial statement that I have.  Do you see any problems?  All of the permissions are 777 so that shouldn't be it.  Could there be any other things I need to take care of on my server?  Everything is in the same folder too.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there's an error in your script, but your webserver is configured to suppress error reporting. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script to force php to display errors if you think that may be the case.

Comment: what if you add "./" so  $target = "./upload/";

Comment: I just set up your exact configuration on my webserver and it worked. The code that you have posted works. There may be an issue with some other part of your html page. Try it with just the form inside <html> tags.

Comment: could you check your php.ini file to see if the function is not in the list of forbidden functions, should that option be activated, also wether open_basedir has been set. Lastly give your input tag an id value, might be it's choking on that if you give a very strict doctype like for example a recent xhtml one

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify that post_max_size and upload_max_filesize is greater than or equal to the size of the file you're attempting to upload?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your max size is > than the size of your file